# How to Automatically sign user in once verification code has verified their account in AWS Cognito sdk nodejs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

how can I automatically sign user  in when they verify their token after registering in AWS cognito nodejs, because at the moment the user has to register to verify the token and then sign in, is there a way to bypass the sign in? and getaccess tokens without user having to retype their credentials. Obviously I could store their credentials in sessionsStorage, but I feel it is not as secure. Any help would be brilliant!

The login function I have at the moment requires a username and password to return the tokens so it won't work if I just call upon that as I don't have the user's password.

Comment: could you please try to replicate this, or provide any code, usually when it is a technical question we add screenshots or snippets of code to make our community easy to provide an answer.